# Apps script - google sheet ,need a help in user form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working on an apps script for my google spreadsheet. In that, I want a search feature that will search in data and brings back it to the user form for updating. I did code with no error but still, the output is not completed. Please help me with this guys!!
this is the code-

```html
var SEARCH_COL_IDX = 0;
function search() {

  
   var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var e    = ss.getSheetByName("ENTRY"); //Form Sheet
  
 
  var str       = e.getRange("G7").getValue();
  var values    = ss.getSheetByName("DATA").getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 2; i < values.length; i++) {
    var row = values[i];
    if (row[SEARCH_COL_IDX] == str) {
    
      
                 e.getRange("D6").setValue(row[0]);
                 e.getRange("H4").setValue(row[1]);
                 e.getRange("D4").setValue(row[2]);
                 e.getRange("D7").setValue(row[3]);
                 e.getRange("D8").setValue(row[4]);
                 e.getRange("D12").setValue(row[5]);
                 e.getRange("D13").setValue(row[6]);
                 e.getRange("D14").setValue(row[7]);
                 e.getRange("D15").setValue(row[8]);
                 e.getRange("D16").setValue(row[9]);
                 e.getRange("H12").setValue(row[10]);
                 e.getRange("H13").setValue(row[11]);
                 e.getRange("H14").setValue(row[12]);
                 e.getRange("H15").setValue(row[13]);
                 e.getRange("H16").setValue(row[14]);
                 e.getRange("H17").setValue(row[15]);
    } }}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please add some details of your DATA sheet including some sample data and a brief description of your efforts to debug your code.

Comment: Can you share a copy of the spreadsheet with dummy data and describe better what are you trying to accomplish? What is the data that is missing from the report and how is the report created, from where does it take the data?